# neo4j remote access via web proxy

Tags: neo4j

I have configured neo4j in a local machine and it can be easily accessed via LAN (with its IP address like 192.168.22.25:7474).

Now I would like to access the neo4j remotely eg. from my home via web proxy.

What I have tried?

I have changed the dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474 in neo4j.conf file.

In server( IP of server 123.123.123.123) machine I have also added ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse  as follow:

ProxyPass /browser *192.168.22.25:7474/browser

ProxyPassReverse /browser *192.168.22.25:7474/browser

(*could not add http:// here since I could not post two links)

I can access the neo4j remotely like

http://123.123.123.123/browser

but when I tried to login then it does not work further.

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Shrestha